# Jquery - Set default option in dynamically polulated dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, drop-down-menu

How do I set a default value in dynamically populated dropdown? Here is my code:

```
function loadCountryModal(countryId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "index.php?task=Admin.getCountryById",
        data: "countryId=" + countryId,
        success: function (jsonData) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
            $("#country").val(obj['data'][0]['name']);

            $.each(obj['data']['regionList'], function () {
                $('#region').append(
                $("<option></option>").text(this.name).val(this.region_id));
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Which dropdown you are talking about? There are two here `#country` and `#region`

Comment: which one do you want to be selected? I mean on which condition?

Comment: First thing would be to try, which you don't seem to have. `selectedIndex` property of your select element is the property you're looking for.

Comment: I'd like #region to be selected after the iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I've forgot to mention ... I'm using Bootstrap's "select2-me" class to skin the dropdown

So different selector method is needed. This is the fix:

`$('select').select2();`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After your $.each loop, add:

```
$('#region').val('default_option_value');
```

Comment: I've tried that: `$('#region').val(obj['data'][0]['region_id']);` without any luck...

Comment: Have you checked what obj['data'][0]['region_id'] is? Write it out to the console to check. In particular, are you sure that obj['data'][0] is the same as obj['data']['regionList'], which is what you're looping on in your $.each?

Comment: It prints out the region_id. Here is a JSON object for you to take a look: `{
    "status": 0,
    "msg": null,
    "data": {
        "0": {
            "country_id": "37",
            "region_id": "5",
            "name": "Botswana",
            "is_active": "1",
            "position": "37",
            "region": "East & South Africa"
        },
        "regionList": [
            {
                "region_id": "4",
                "name": "Asia & Pacific",
                "is_active": "1",
                "position": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
    "count": 0
}`

Comment: So obj['data'][0]['region_id'] should return "5" in this case? Was an <option value="5">xxxxx</option> added to #region as a result of the $.each loop?

Comment: Yes, it has been added, but the option is not selected, that's the problem :) I use bootstrap "select2-me" class to skin the dropdwon. I'm not sure whether that's the issue or not...

Answer (score 0):

just use `.attr("selected",true);`

```
$("#country").val(obj['data'][0]['name']).attr("selected",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#region').val('valueToSelect');
```